# Add object without deleting old data stored on variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to add `Thread` objects to my variable `threads`. Here is my function:

```
newThreads: Thread[];
newThreadsId : string[];
threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;

addThread(keyThread: string, newThread: Thread): void {
   this.threadService.newThreads.push(newThread);
   this.threadService.newThreadsId.push(newThreadId);

   let result = {[this.threadService.newThreadsId]: this.threadService.newThreads};

   this.threadService.threads = Observable.of(result);
   this.threadService.threads = Observable.of(result);
}
```

I have this error :

```
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any

Type 'Observable<{ [x: string]: Thread[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread; }>'. Type '{ [x: string]: Thread[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: Thread; }'. Index signatures are incompatible. Type 'Thread[]' is not assignable to type 'Thread'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'Thread[]'.
```

Is it possible to add data in the variable threads?

Comment: Is `threads` a collection or an array? You seem to be overwriting it, instead of adding to it.

Comment: @nondestructive
I think threads is a collection. It's initialize like this : `threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;`

Comment: how do you consume  `this.threadService.threads` ? It looks like you are using rxjs wrong

Comment: @HaneTV
I consume this.threadServicve.threads like this : `this.threads = messageService.messages
      .map((messages: Message[]) => {
        const threads: { [key: string]: Thread } = {};
        messages.map((message: Message) => {
          threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id] ||
            message.thread;
        });
        return threads;
      });`


Do you know how to do it ? Or is that feasible?